# new instance of class in typescript

Tags: typescript, class, angular6

I working with angular 6. I want to create a new instance of a class but I get a warning between the "WARNING" text in the following line.

Error text: "EntityLocationGetDto is not defined"

Also, I created a constructor but not worked again.

That's my codes;

customer.ts:

```
abstract class EntityGetDto<PK> {
    public Id: PK;
    public CreatedDate: Date;
    public UpdateDate: Date;
    public CreatedBy: string;
    public UpdatedBy: string;
}
abstract class EntityLocationGetDto<PK> extends EntityGetDto<PK> {
    public StateId?: string;
    public CityId?: string;
    public CountyId?: string;
}
export class CustomerCartDto extends EntityLocationGetDto<string> {
    FullName: string;
    Adress?: string;
    PostCode?: string;
    Email?: string;
    Web?: string;
    TaxOffice?: string;
    TaxIdNumber?: string;
    PhoneNumber?: string;
    MobileNumber?: string;
    FaxNumber?: string;
    BirthDay?: Date;
}
```

customer.service.ts:

```
import { CustomerCartDto } from './customer';
@Injectable()
export class CustomerService {
constructor() { }
getById(customerId: string): CustomerCartDto {
    const custId: string = customerId.replace('xx', '');
   WARNING =>  const res: CustomerCartDto = new CustomerCartDto(); <= WARNING 
    res.FullName = 'xx' + custId;
    res.Email = 'xx_' + custId + '@hotmail.com';
    res.Web = 'xx.com';
    res.PhoneNumber = null;
    res.MobileNumber = '0123456789';
    res.FaxNumber = null;
    res.BirthDay = null;
    res.Id = 'xx' + custId;
    res.CreatedDate = new Date();
    res.UpdateDate = new Date();
    res.CreatedBy = null;
    res.UpdatedBy = null;
    return res;
  }
}
```

Also, it works like this;

```
const res: CustomerCartDto = {
      FullName: 'xx' + custId,
      Email: 'xx_' + custId + '@hotmail.com',
      Web: 'xx.com',
      PhoneNumber: null,
      MobileNumber: '0123456789',
      FaxNumber: null,
      BirthDay: null,
      Id: 'xx' + custId,
      CreatedDate: new Date(),
      UpdateDate: new Date(),
      CreatedBy: null,
      UpdatedBy: null
    };
```

Thanks.

Comment: which line throws that error. Trying your code I can't reproduce it

Comment: sorry, I forget. I updated.

Comment: that should work because of typescript interfaces. sorry i can't reproduce your warning

Comment: me too. I don't understand why getting this error.